# Magento 2 How to change the order of input fields of first name and last name

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I want to swap the order of the *first name* and *last name* fields on the account creation page.

[image: screenshot create new customer account]

I would like to provide input fields tailored to Japanese.
Please tell me if you know how to do it.

Comment: Don't understand. What do you want? please explain

Comment: I would like to change the order of input fieald the first name and the last name.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to **change the order of entering the first name and the last name** to  the account creation page, So you have  to do some changes at the template`(.phtml)` level.

First, let you know that Magento manages the position of first and last name statically at the code level for this form.See at [view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml#L29).

***From this phtml code, hope you will understand by change code position you easily swipe the positions***